# Form->end without a div in CakePHP

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'd like to create a submit button that does NOT have a `<div>` around it.  I assumed using the `inputDefaults` would make this happen like it does for all of the forms inputs, but - no luck.

Obviously I could just create a submit button via HTML, without CakePHP, but - I was hoping there'd be a cake answer.  Here's what I've tried:

```
$this->Form->create(false, array('inputDefaults' => array('div'=>false)));
$this->Form->end('Submit');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('div'=>false));
```

Should do what you are after. The other example may have been Cake 1.2 or something; not sure.

It also appears you can just do this instead:

```
<?php 
$options = array(
    'label' => 'Update',
    'value' => 'Update!',
    'div' => false
    )
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
```

That looks more cakey.